# How to block notifications in a certain period?

Tags: notifications

I get notifications all day long, which always interrupt me while I'm working. So, I'd like to know if there is a way to block all these notifications in a certain period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "Automatic rules" in Do not Disturb menu , there you can create an event/timerule named "work" give time period and occurrence of the event . Select the profile you want in this i would prefer priority only . If you still want some notifications you can increase priority of those notifications in app setting of that particular app .

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work for me. If I'm not wrong, then I can activate the notifications I prefer by enabling "Priority display".